# window.onload and <body onload=“”/> have different results. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onload

This is a corollary to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993075/createhtmldocument-does-not-initialize), and possibly an extension of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload). I was playing with `createHTMLDocument()`, trying to set an `onload` event to trigger it. The following code (based on code found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument)) uses an inline `onload` and works just dandy:

```
<div>
  <iframe id="frame" src="about:blank"> </iframe>
</div>

<script>
  function makeDocument() {
  var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

  var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");
  var p = doc.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = "This is a new paragraph.";
  doc.body.appendChild(p);

  var destDocument = frame.contentDocument;
  var srcNode = doc.documentElement;
  var newNode = destDocument.importNode(srcNode, true);

  destDocument.replaceChild(newNode, destDocument.documentElement);
  console.log(destDocument.readyState);
}
</script>
<body onload="makeDocument()"></body>
```

However, if I try to load `makeDocument()` with `window.onload` the function fires too early, before something (not sure what) that is required by `createHTMLDocument()` is loaded. Here's the code (with some redundancies removed):

```
<div>
  <iframe id="frame" src="about:blank"> </iframe>
</div>
<script>
  function makeDocument() {
    // same as previous
  }
  window.onload = makeDocument();
</script>
```

If you run this you'll notice that not only is the text not added to the frame, but that, as the console output indicates, the inner document cannot be initialized at the time `window.onload` is fired. Why not?

I have read in [various places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191318/2741229) that `window.onload` and inline `onload` are essentially the same thing. But then [maybe not really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload#comment12426117_191318). If anyone could explain this to me you'd make me a very happy person indeed.

Comment: You should be assigning `makeDocument` to `window.onload`, not invoking it. Drop the `()`.

Comment: The reason the `<body onload=` version gets the `()` is because the string you provide becomes the body of a separate function that is assigned to `window.onload`, so it effectively becomes `window.onload = function(event) { makeDocument(); };`

Comment: That was it! Simple as that. All that time to write this up and all I had to do was hit backspace twice.

Comment: One more question: so what was happening was that when I was trying to assign the function to `window.onload`, I was actually invoking the function?

Comment: Yes, it was being invoked, and its return value was being assigned to `window.onload`. In the case of that function, the return value was `undefined`.